# How do I reference ObjectID in another collection in MongoDB & Node?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm fairly new to this, so bear with me, however I have 2 collections.  One called photos and another called users.

In Node, I am taking the data and putting it into my MongoDB using mongoose.  I've got this working fine with my Schema:

```
var picSchema = new Schema({
        uid: String,
        pid: String,
        oFile: String
});
```

What I want to do though is for the uid, I want to add the ObjectId for the user uploading the photo.  I can pass this as a String, however I thought that I would have had to have the field set as an ObjectId, but seems I cannot do this?

Unless I am missing something, I might as well just add the username in there and use that as a reference?

Answer (score 2):

Use `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` to populate the field with an ObjectId. In this case, you would use `User` (or whatever the name of your User schema is).

```
var picSchema = new Schema({
            uid: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
            pid: String,
            oFile: String
});
```

Further to this, you can also use the Mongoose method `Populate` if you wish to expand the User document within a `Pic` document. For example:

```
Pic.find({})
  .populate('uid')
  .exec(function(err, pic) {
    console.log(pic);
    // do something
});
```

Comment: how to implement the auto-populate in this scenario?